# Sugar ORM SUM a column

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Does anyone know if it is possible to sum a column using Sugar ORM? I've tried to find any documentation, and there is a raw query method, however, the raw query method does not have any returning values.

Example: "select sum(price) from atable"

Class.executeQuery() is void.

Sugar ORM does not seem very usable until this kind of features (along with JOIN etc) are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally do it with the following code:

```
long sumValue = -1L;
Database db = ((Application)SugarApp.getSugarContext()).obtainDatabase();
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getDB();
SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(
    "SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name");
try {
    sumValue = sqLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong();
} catch (Exception var16) {
    var16.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    sqLiteStatement.close();
}
```

Also need to change the Application class to can access to the DataBase property because has protected access (don't forget to modify the manifest properly).

```
public class Application extends SugarApp {    
    public Database obtainDatabase(){
        return getDatabase();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform raw queries by accessing sugar database object by reflection:

```
int sumValue = -1;
Field f = null;
try {
    f = SugarContext.getSugarContext().getClass().getDeclaredField("sugarDb");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    SugarDb db = (SugarDb) f.get(SugarContext.getSugarContext());
    Cursor cursor = db.getDB().
            rawQuery("Select Sum(COLUMN_NAME) as s from TABLE_NAME" , null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        sumValue = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("s"));
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! This should be the accepted one! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great answer but I think its better to use android basic db coding style in these kind of scenarios like custom queries as sugar does not fully support on this :D

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem possible at present time. I ended up using [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) instead, a much faster (not depending on reflection) solution which gives access to the SQLiteDatabase-object, enabling all kind of custom possibilities.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue on SUM a column on Sugar, with custom query also not possible !!  http://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html ?

Comment: sugar orm sucks ! solved this  sum issue by filtering the retrieved List http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699131/sum-value-of-class-objects-property-in-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

The answer might be too late, but it will help new comers, its pretty easy to `query` custom `queries` to the `database` in order to `SUM` or use any query you could obtain access to the `Database` by the following code:

```
SugarDb sugarDb = new SugarDb(context);
```

then its pretty straight forward to `query` the `database` for example you could do

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = sugarDb.getDB();
    SQLiteStatement query = database.compileStatement("SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM EXPENSES_MODEL");
    try {
        total = query.simpleQueryForLong();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        query.close();
    }
```

> notice the underscore in table name? its how Sugar ORM names our tables so please be careful when calling the table.

---

> notice how the column name is capitalised? its because Sugar ORM capitalise each column.

---